# Emacs web-mode tabs not working

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs web-mode to edit my php files and have noticed that the tab key doesn't work the way I expect it to in a couple of different situations.  For example if I have a string that spans multiple lines like this...

```
<?php
return "
<nav>
<a href='index.php?page=skills'>My skills and background</a>
<a href='index.php?page=projects'>Some projects</a>
</nav>
";
?>
```

and I go to the beginning of the lines with anchor tags and press tab nothing happens.  I have to use the space bar to indent the lines the way I want.

The other situation is occurs inside of a php block for example

```
<?php 
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1);
$pageData = new stdClass();
$pageData->title = "Jordan: Portfolio site";
$pageData->content = include_once "views/navigation.php";
$navigationIsClicked = isset($_GET['page']);
if($navigationIsClicked) {
    $fileToLoad = $_GET['page'];
    $pageData->content .= "<p>Will soon load $fileToLoad.php</p>";
}
$page = include_once "templates/page.php";
echo $page;
?>
```

if I go to one of the variable assignment lines and push tab nothing happens, again spaces work fine, then inside the if block only 1 tab is allowed.  Is there any way to change how this mode uses tabs in my .emacs file.  I currently have this in my .emacs

```
(defun my-setup-php ()
  ;; enable web mode
  (web-mode)

  ;; make these variables local
  (make-local-variable 'web-mode-code-indent-offset)
  (make-local-variable 'web-mode-markup-indent-offset)
  (make-local-variable 'web-mode-css-indent-offset)

  ;; set indentation, can set different indentation level for different code type
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 4)
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2))


(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php$" . my-setup-php))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out my question is completely unrelated to web-mode.  The function that emacs binds to the tab key by default is called `indent-for-tab-command` the function I was looking for is called `tab-to-tab-stop` which by default is bound to M - i.  This [website](http://www.pement.org/emacs_tabs.htm) has a very detailed explanation of how the tab key works in emacs and how to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)`

Comment: I tried this and the behavior of the tab key is unchanged.  Perhaps I just don't understand how the tab key in emacs works.  Thanks anyways